# Redirection after a process has started

Tags: io-redirection

Say I have called firefox from the terminal with `firefox`, and I got back to the terminal.  I can now suspend the process with ctrl-z, and resume it in the background with `bg`.  However it will continue to produce output in the terminal.  Is there a way to redirect that at this point?  That is, to get the result of having written `firefox &>/dev/null &` to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `gdb`. You'll need to find the process ID (PID) for firefox, which may be included in the suspend message if you've paused the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

If that message doesn't contain the PID in your terminal, you can find it using something like:

```
ps aux | grep firefox
```

With that, you can use this command to launch `gdb`:

```
sudo gdb -p PID
```

Within the program, these commands will then redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

```
p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),1)
p dup2(open("/dev/null",0),2)
detach
quit
```

Comment: As long as the process is yours, you shouldn't need the sudo.  Repeat this mantra "sudo only when absolutely necessary."

Comment: @MAP Good point. Using Mint, `gdb` won't to attach to a process without sudo, even if I own the process. I'll check this on a CentOS install later and possibly update my answer.

Comment: OK, the machines I have open windows on now don't include any mints, and the only linux doesn't even seem to *have* gdb.  So I can only confirm that on NetBSD it works fine without the sudo.